# Php move files strange bug

Tags: php

I'm facing a strange bug that I can't find words to describe !
When I use `move_uploaded_file` function with this path "/Project/Uploads/Imgs/"
When I use the same function with this path "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Project/Uploads/Imgs/"
It works normally !

**My code**

```
$avatar         = $_FILES['avatar'];
$avatarName     = filter_var($avatar['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$avatarTmp      = $avatar['tmp_name'];
$randomAvatar   = rand(0,1000000000) . "_" . $avatarName;
move_uploaded_file($avatarTmp, $uploads . $randomAvatar);
```

While Variable `$uploads` = the path

Another bug,
Every time PHP moves the file into the uploads folder, I've to make chown from the linux terminal with sudo permissions to make it readable

Comment: Check your permissions, I highly doubt `move_uploaded_file` has any issues with itself.

Comment: I've done many checks with permissions to know what exactly is the problem.
but if it was permissions problem, why does changing the path solve it ?

Comment: Try with this so you got full directory path $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/Project/Uploads/Imgs/"

Comment: I saw the same question the other day, but I can't find it now. Anyway, the `/` at the start of your path makes it an absolute path to the system, meaning there has to be a `Project` folder in the root of your system, which there probably isn't. You'd have to use a relative path compared to your script or document root.

Comment: Yes, because I'm in another folder,
I'm in folder called "/Project/dashboard" for example
I want to move to "/Project/Uploads/Imgs/"
I've tried using double dots "../Uploads/Imgs/"
But it didn't solve the problem

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /Project/Uploads/Imgs/` in your console?

Comment: *"I've to make chown from the linux terminal with sudo permissions to make it readable"* -- readable **by who**?

Comment: Readable by browser

Comment: The browser runs on a different machine, it cannot read the files from your server anyway. You mean *readable by the web server*. Or do you test the application on your computer and attempt to open the file directly in the browser (by double-clicking it in the file manager) using the `file://` protocol?

Comment: This is the output
drwxrwxrwx 2 $User $User 4096 Jul 14 18:54 .

Comment: Well,
I'm using chromium browser
but when i try to call the img using <img src='<?php echo $uploads . $img; ?>' />
It says that img not found
so, I've to chown to make the img exists to the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it
Basically, I just had to change the path from `/Project/Uploads/Imgs` to `../Uploads/Imgs`
Well, At first this wasn't working.
But, I discovered that it was a bug from chromium browser or something, cause when I've restarted the browser, and changed the path, It worked fine !

The Second Bug also was a bug from the browser
I don't know how, but The second bug was fixed after restarting the browser.